# How To Display Strings in JTextarea/JTextfield

Tags: java

Pretty basic question for you. I am new to Java, and so far have made some relatively simple Javascript programs. One particular favourite of mine is one I call The Perfect Insult, and I have decided to develop it properly, so I can say I've made a program.

The core program isn't finished yet, but what I've done so far is enough. There will be some calculations to decide which response the computer chould give, but all the variables will remain the same. I just need to know how to print the code to a JTextArea or a JTextField rather that `System.out`. Any help would be much appreciated :).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class tpiCore {

    public class rootInterface extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField input;

        public void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        rootInterface frame = new rootInterface();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public rootInterface() {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 550);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);

            input = new JTextField();
            input.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 11));
            input.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            input.setBounds(10, 447, 414, 54);
            contentPane.add(input);
            input.setColumns(10);

            JEditorPane dtrpnThePerfectInsult = new JEditorPane();
            dtrpnThePerfectInsult.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            dtrpnThePerfectInsult.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            dtrpnThePerfectInsult.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            dtrpnThePerfectInsult.setText("        The Perfect Insult");
            dtrpnThePerfectInsult.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 35);
            contentPane.add(dtrpnThePerfectInsult);

            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            textArea.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            textArea.setBounds(10, 57, 414, 383);
            contentPane.add(textArea);

            }
        }

        public static void core(String args[]) {
            String[] insults = new String[15];
            insults[0] = "insult 0";
            insults[1] = "insult 1";
            insults[2] = "insult 2";
            insults[3] = "insult 3";
            insults[4] = "insult 4";
            insults[5] = "insult 5";
            insults[6] = "insult 6";
            insults[7] = "insult 7";
            insults[8] = "insult 8";
            insults[9] = "insult 9";
            insults[10] = "insult 10";
            insults[11] = "insult 11";
            insults[12] = "insult 12";
            insults[13] = "insult 13";
            insults[14] = "insult 14";
            double count = 0;

            System.out.println("Come on then, hit me with your best shot!");

            while (count<10) {
                String insult1 = insults[(new Random()).nextInt(insults.length)];
                System.out.println(insult1);
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                input.nextLine();
                String response = input.toString();
                count++;
            } 

            System.out.println("Okay, I give in. You win.");

            }

        }
```

Comment: First of all, you should know that JavaScript and Java are not the same. That is Java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JTextArea.setText(string)
JTextArea.append(string)
```

java doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html